# Beamer - Put "Joint work with A and B"

Tags: beamer, titles

I need to put "Joint work with A and B" on the title page of my slide for a talk on a conference. I didn't find a very clear way to do this, just found a code like below.

```
\title{Group Theory}
\author{My name}
\institute[My Inst.]{Full Institut Name}
% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Logo1}\hspace*{4.75cm}~%
   \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Logo2}
}
\date{\today \\ \vspace{1cm} \tiny{Joint work with A and B}}
```

Although basically the title page looks fine, on the right bottom corner of each page, the date disappears and the page number is missing.

Please help me to put the phrase "Joint work with ..." on the title page, please.

Comment: Use `\author[My Name]{My name\\ \vspace{1cm} \tiny{Joint work with A and B}}`

Comment: Or, if you want to keep the note below the date - the same for `\date[\today]{\today \\[1cm]\tiny{Joint work with A and B}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `\author`, `date`, and `\title` there is an optional argument, that is used in the structure of the frame (i.e. the footline) so you could use

```
\title[Group Theory]{A longer title of the talk concerning Group Theory}
\author[short name]{My full name}
\institute[My Inst.]{Full Institut Name}
% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Logo1}\hspace*{4.75cm}~%
   \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Logo2}
}
\date[\today]{\today \\ \vspace{1cm} \tiny{Joint work with A and B}}
```

to recover the footline you wanted.
Without the shortened `date` your date-field in the footline takes more than one line and the slide number (being placed at the bottom of the footline) vanishes.

Comment: Good to have the solution with the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an other method.
You entierly define here your title page.
This template is to be modified.

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Definitions (do not change this)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter \def\printtitle{{\centering \@title\par}}\makeatother % Title                         
\makeatletter \def\printauthor{{\centering \large \@author}}\makeatother % Author                   
\makeatletter \def\printauthor{{\centering \large \@institute}}\makeatother % Institute                 
\makeatletter \def\printauthor{{\centering \large \@date}}\makeatother % Date                   

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Metadata (Change this)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{ \Large \textsc{Technisches Projekt}     % Subtitle of the document
    \\[0.5cm]% 0.5cm spacing
    \huge \textbf{\uppercase{Vorläufige Konstruktionsforschung v0.8}} % Title
      }
\institute{vfdvfs}

\author{Hans  Schnoggeloch}    
\date{\today \\ \vspace{1cm} \tiny{Joint work with A and B}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
```

This method works, but I also like and use the method given in the comments.

Comment: I don't think, the example works; don't you have to redefine the footline-print-short-date part to overcome the problem stated by the OP? Your example looks like redefining some commands used on the titlepage (if i'm seeing that correctly, didn't compile). The kind of "more readable" way would be to define your own `titlepage` by defining a titlepage for your style (`\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{yourstyle}` and (to overcome the OPs problem) an own footline not printing the date as it is given in your example (sorry for the long post).